# 403 error after changing `DocumentRoot` to `/home/` subdirectory

Tags: apache-2.4

I've got Apache set up on a remote server.

Here's the contents of file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@example.com
     ServerName example.com
     ServerAlias images.example.com
     DocumentRoot /home/myUserName/var/www/example.com/public_html/
     ErrorLog /home/myUserName/var/www/example.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /home/myUserName/var/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I've set up the right "A" and "AAAA" records with my hosting provider. But when I go to `http://images.example.com`, I get a 403 error.

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at images.example.com Port 80
```

How do I set things up so that going to `http://images.example.com` lets me see the contents of `/home/myUserName/var/www/example.com/public_html/`?

**Update**

Contents of `error.log`:

```
[Sun May 20 21:37:05.305775 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 4858] [client 2601:587:5:6a70:428d:5cff:fe71:b1e4:56518] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/myUserName/var/www/example.com/public_html/
[Sun May 20 21:41:15.517163 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 4859] [client 51.38.12.23:42405] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/myUserName/var/www/example.com/public_html/
[Sun May 20 21:43:49.090780 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 4860] [client 2601:587:5:6a70:428d:5cff:fe71:b1e4:56678] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/myUserName/var/www/example.com/public_html/
[Sun May 20 21:48:59.756624 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 4861] [client 179.127.179.39:43803] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/myUserName/var/www/example.com/public_html/
[Sun May 20 21:53:22.709395 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 4864] [client 178.73.215.171:28502] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/myUserName/var/www/example.com/public_html/
```

Running `ls -la /home/myUserName/var/www/example.com/public_html/` outputs this:

```
total 12
drwxrwxr-x  3 myUserName myUserName 4096 May 20 22:58 .
drwxrwxr-x  4 myUserName myUserName 4096 May 20 21:32 ..
drwxr-xr-x 13 myUserName myUserName 4096 Apr 14 02:18 tile
```

Comment: Check your error log. Then check your permissions.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Updated question

Comment: @kubanczyk Running `chown www-data var -R` and then restarting Apache service still gives the 403 error

Comment: As was stated in the accepted answer to the duplicate question, you need to make sure that the `www-data` user has execute permissions for each directory in the entire path. Changing the permissions of part of the chain, starting at `/home/myUsername/var` is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First verify that basic access to files works, by putting a file in that directory and accessing it directly via the proper URL. Requesting a directory/ path either opens the corresponding DirectoryIndex file, or gives a 403 if there isn't any, which adds to the confusion.

Regarding your question. If I understood right that opening / should display the contents of that directory, this can be achieved by either writing a custom listing script in php and such, or by just letting Apache `mod_autoindex` do it by enabling `Options +Indexes` and tweaking its settings.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a directory and options to allow access, and 403 error I think that in the directory home there is no file like index.html, index.php also it could mean that you didn't set "Require all granted" option. 
Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com
     ServerName example.com
     ServerAlias images.example.com
     DocumentRoot "/home/myUserName/var/www/example.com/public_html/"
     ErrorLog /home/myUserName/var/www/example.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /home/myUserName/var/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined
    <Directory "/home/myUserName/var/www/example.com/public_html">
      Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
      DirectoryIndex index.html index.php 
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

To see the contents of the the directory change -Indexes to +Indexes

Comment: Added the `<Directory>` block, but I still get the 403 error

Comment: @Username is there a "Require all granted",  also check that no  slash added after the /public_html/ remove it only in the Directory path,  and keep it in the DocumentRoot

Comment: @Username also remove the "DirectoryIndex index.html index.php" if you just want to see the content and don't forget to change -Indexes to +Indexes

Comment: Tried those. Same error

Comment: @Username do you have a .htaccess file in your directory home? look at this https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration

Comment: @Username Try chmod a+x /home/myUserName/var/www/example.com/public_html/